# Viewstate MAC failed error in ASP.NET using Autogenerate key, not on farm or cluster

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, machinekey

Error is:
"Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

- I am not hosting on a Web Farm or cluster.
- Application has about 100 users.
- Only 1 user getting this message.
- User only getting this error message in IE11, not when using other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) which leads me to believe this is browser related.
- Running IE11 in no-addons mode same error.
- Autogenerate machine key defaults in IIS are untouched.

My goal is to figure out what is causing this, and not just a quick fix.

If anyone has had this same situation happen to them and can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out what was causing this issue, but I managed to fix it.

In IE11 developer tools (F12), emulation tab, I switched the Document Mode from Edge to IE10, and then back to Edge. No joke, this fixed the issue.

Sometimes just turning things off and then back on fixes the problem. If anyone knows why this could clear something up additional comments are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, ASP ViewState uses the client/server MAC addresses as default encryption keys scrambling the ViewState data.  This is to ensure that the client-sever pair which initially loaded the website are the same on all subsequent connections.  If this fails, the assumption is the MAC address is different on the server side because of a cluster or server farm hosting the website does not reconnect the client to the exact same server when they submit a webpage as it did when it was loaded.  This is why specifying a Key overrides the need to use both MAC addresses as keys.  However, this may or may not be the case.  It is a misleading error title assumes the underlying cause of the error.

If you happen to be using a MasterPage in ASP, the default for IE is IE.master otherwise it is Default.Master for all other browsers.  If this are located in two different folders, they could have two different web.config files specifying <machineKey> differently (or not at all).

In MSVS, there are also Debug vs Release web.config files which may have differing <machineKey> settings.

I've also had issues with PLESK hosting.  Even though there is no load-balancing, redundant tandem processing, server cluster or farm, or proxies, this hosting software has some unique quarks when specifying web.config files.  If had problems with uploaded web.config files have been overwritten whenever web-accessed settings are changed.  (this overwrote my web.config file to an auto-generated one).  As well, the default session time out is different for PLESK (5 vs 20 minutes...if that matters).

On webhosts which aren't dedicated servers, I'm wondering if there's any cross-pollination when more than one ASP application specifies a <machineKey>.  This would be case-by-case dependent on which IIS/LASP/PLESK type hosting software is running.

With there being so many different encryption protocols (SHA1 | MD5 | 3DES | AES | HMACSHA256 | HMACSHA384 | HMACSHA512), I wonder which one you're using in particular and is IE has a problem with that protocol.

I will proffer these possibles and let others chime in to either debunk or expand.  I must admit, ASP's ViewState encryption smoke and mirrors have been a bane of my existence.